# insertion sort in python vs javascript

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, insertion-sort

I implemented insertion sort using python and javascript.  For some strange reason, the JS code works, and the python code doesn't.  Both implementations should do the same thing.  I traced over every line of the code, and couldn't find a difference between the two. Take a look and see if you can spot what is different with the python code.

**Javascript Code:**

```
function insertionSort(nums) {

  for (let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    const value = nums[i];
    let hole = i;

    while (hole >= 0 && nums[hole-1] > value) {
      nums[hole] = nums[hole-1];
      hole = hole - 1;
    }
    nums[hole] = value;
  }
  return nums;
}


const sorted = insertionSort([5,2,1,3,6,4]);
console.log(sorted);
```

**Python Code:**

```
def insertion_sort(nums):
  for i in range(0,len(nums)):
    value = nums[i]
    hole = i

    while hole >= 0 and nums[hole-1] > value:
      nums[hole] = nums[hole-1]
      hole = hole - 1

    nums[hole] = value
  return nums

sorts = insertion_sort([5,2,1,3,6,4])
print(sorts)
```

Comment: Apparently they don’t do the same thing (because one is reportedly broken). What debugging has been done? Eg. what state is unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python and javascript have different ideas about what `someList[-1]` does.

In your code above you evaluate `nums[hole-1]`. The way you've written your loop this can be `nums[-1]` when `hole` is zero. In the python code this gets the last element of the list. In the javascript code this is undefined.  This has a significant effect on what the next part: `nums[hole-1] > value` means.

In the end you don't need to calculate `while hole >= 0 and nums[hole-1] > value` when the value of `hole` is `0`, so maybe changing `>=` to `>` will be a good option.

Comment: ahh makes perfect sense.  so when the hole is at 0, no need to execute the loop.  and the -1 index for python vs. undefined in javascript makes sense why the output is different.  Thanks a bunch @markmeyer!

Answer (score 2):

```
  nums[hole] = nums[hole-1]
```

If `hole == 0`, `nums[hole-1]` becomes `nums[-1]`, which gets the last element of the list. This is not what it does in Javascript.